# "Object Required" Error for Coloring Adjacent Cell (if, ActiveCell.Offset)

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I was hoping someone could troubleshoot my sub. I previously had quite a long sub running perfectly fine, then I added one more if statement and now I'm getting an Object Required error. I'm trying to search the whole sheet and any cell which has a value of "Google Inc." would then color the cell 2 to the left.

Ex. Cell E7 is "Google Inc.", so cell C7 would be colored Aqua. I can't see a reason the below wouldn't work so maybe someone else can!

```
ElseIf cell.Value = "Google Inc." Then 
ActiveCell.Offset(0,-2).Interior.colour = X1RgbColour.rgbAqua
```

Thanks!

Comment: `X1RgbColour.rgbAqua` is vb.net, not vba and it is `XLRgbColour.rgbAqua` in any case. Note **L** not **1**.

Comment: `X1RgbColour.rgbAqua` works perfectly fine in VBA.

Comment: Ah! Shoot there it is - fixed the 1 and totally solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @cyboashu - I changed X1RgbColour to X**L**RgbColour and ran `?XLRgbColour.rgbAqua` through the VBE's Immediate window. It comes back as error 424.

Comment: @Jeeped but `?XLRgbColor.rgbAqua` returns `16776960`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Could be I'm missing a library reference.

Comment: Yours was spelled `Colour` not `Color` @Jeeped

Comment: @ScottCraner  -Now **I'm** making Canadians look bad!

Answer (score 1):

First, you will want to spell `Color` the way Americans do. Secondly, for the color you can use VB constants like `vbBlue`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, Canadian brain. Adjusted the spelling but still getting the same error.

Comment: You're making Canadians look bad.

Comment: Unintentional @Jeeped

Comment: @JDodge did you also change the color to something like `vbBlue`?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that comment was going to @JDodge as it was immediately below his/hers.